# Does "unit test only one thing" means one feature or one whole scenario of a unit?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, automated-tests

When people say "test only one thing". Does that mean that test one feature at a time or one scenario at a time?

```
method() {
    //setup data
    def data = new Data()
    //send external webservice call 
    def success = service.webserviceCall(data)
    //persist
    if (success) {
        data.save()
    }
}
```

Based on the example, do we test by feature of the method:

```
testA() //test if service.webserviceCall is called properly, so assert if called once with the right parameter
testB() //test if service.webserviceCall succeeds, assert that it should save the data
testC() //test if service.webserviceCall fails, assert that it should not save the data
```

By scenario:

```
testA() //test if service.webserviceCall succeeds, so assert if service is called once with the right parameter, and assert that the data should be saved
testB() //test if service.webserviceCall fails, so again assert if service is called once with the right parameter, then assert that it should not save the data
```

I'm not sure if this is a subjective topic, but I'm trying to do the by feature approach. I got the idea from Roy Osherove's blogs, but I'm not sure if I understood it correct.

It was mentioned there that it would be easier to isolate the errors, but I'm not sure if its overkill. Complex methods will tend to have lots of tests.

(Please excuse my wording on the by feature/scenario, I'm not sure how to word them)

Comment: I believe they are referring to features, as scenarios are variable--by testing features of a method, you are essentially covering all possible scenarios

Answer (score 1):

You are right in that this is a subjective topic.
Think about how you want this method to behave, not just on how it's currently implemented. Otherwise your tests will just mirror the production code and will break everytime the implementation changes. 
Based on the limited context provided, I'd write the following (separate) tests:

- Is the webservice command called with the expected data?
- If the command returns successfully, is the data saved? Don't overspecify the arguments provided to your webservice call here, as the previous test covers this.
- If it's important that the data is not saved when the command returns a failure, I'd write a third test for this. If it's not important, I wouldn't even bother.

You might have heard the adage "one assert per test". This is good advice in general because a test stops executing as soon as a single assert fails. All asserts further down are not executed. By splitting up the asserts in multiple tests you will receive more feedback when something goes wrong. When tests go red, you know exactly all the asserts that fail and don't have to run through the -fix assertion failure, run tests, fix next assertion failure, repeat- cycle.

So in the terminology you propose, my approach would also be to write a test per feature of the method.

*Sidenote*: you construct your data object in the method itself and call the save method of that object. How do you sense that the data is saved in your tests?

Comment: To answer your sidenote, I usually use a mock datastore api like dbunit. Then I just query them on my assertions.

Answer (score 1):

I understand it like this:
"unit test one thing" == "unit test one behavior"
(After all, it is the behavior that the client wants!)

I would suggest that you approach your testing "one feature at a time". I agree with you where you quoted that with this approach it is "easier to isolate the errors". Roy Osherove really does know what he is talking about especially when it comes to TDD.

In my experience I like to focus on the behaviors that I am trying to test (and I am not particularly referring to BDD here). Essentially I would test each behavior that I am expecting from this code. You said that you are mocking out the dependencies (webservice, and data storage) so I would still class this as a unit test with the following expected behaviors:

- a call to this method will result in a particular call to a web service
- a successful web service call will result in the data being saved
- an unsuccessful web service call will result in the data not being saved

Having tests for these three behaviors will help you isolate any issues with the code immediately.

Your tests should also have no dependency on the actual code written to achieve the behavior. For example, if my implementation called some decorator internal to my class which in turn called the webservice correctly then that should be no concern of my test. My test should only be concerned with the external dependencies and public interface of the class itself.
If I exposed internal methods of my class (or implementation details, such as the decorator mentioned above) for the purposes of testing its particular implementation then I have created brittle tests that will fail when the implementation changes.

In summary, I would recommend that your tests should lock down the behavior of a class and isolate failures to identify the 'unit of behavior' that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

A unit test in general is a test that is done without a call to database or file system or even to that effect doesnot call a webservice either. The idea of a unit test is that if you did not have any internet connection you should be able to unit test. So having said that , if a method calls a webservice or calls a database, then you basically are expected to mock the responses from an external system. You should be testing that unit of work only. As mentioned above by prgmtc on how you should be asserting one assert per method is the way to go.

Second, if you are calling a real webservice or database etc, then consider calling those test as integrated or integration test depending upon what you are trying to test.

Comment: yeah, I agree, I failed to mention that in my examples, all of the external calls/ db calls are mocked.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion to get the most out of TDD you want to be doing test first development.  Have a look at uncle Bobs [3 Rules of TDD](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheThreeRulesOfTdd).

If you follow these rules strictly, you end up writing tests that generally only have a single assert statements.  In reality you will often find you end up with a number of assert statements that act as a single logical assert as it often helps with the understanding of the unit test itself.

Here is an example

```
        [Test]
    public void ValidateBankAccount_GivenInvalidAccountType_ShouldReturnValidationFailure()
    {
        //---------------Set up test pack-------------------
        const string validBankAccount = "99999999999";
        const string validBranchCode = "222222";
        const string invalidAccountType = "99";
        const string invalidAccoutTypeResult = "3";
        var bankAccountValidation = Substitute.For<IBankAccountValidation>();
        bankAccountValidation.ValidateBankAccount(validBankAccount, validBranchCode, invalidAccountType)
            .Returns(invalidAccoutTypeResult);
        var service = new BankAccountCheckingService(bankAccountValidation);
        //---------------Assert Precondition----------------

        //---------------Execute Test ----------------------
        var result = service.ValidateBankAccount(validBankAccount, validBranchCode, invalidAccountType);
        //---------------Test Result -----------------------
        Assert.IsFalse(result.IsValid);
        Assert.AreEqual("Invalid account type", result.Message);
    }
```

And the ValidationResult class that is returned from the service

```
    public interface IValidationResult
{
    bool IsValid { get; }
    string Message { get; }
}

public class ValidationResult : IValidationResult
{
    public static IValidationResult Success()
    {
        return new ValidationResult(true,"");
    }

    public static IValidationResult Failure(string message)
    {
        return new ValidationResult(false, message);
    }

    public ValidationResult(bool isValid, string message)
    {
        Message = message;
        IsValid = isValid;
    }

    public bool IsValid { get; private set; }
    public string Message { get; private set; }
}
```

Note I would have unit tests the ValidationResult class itself, but in the test above I feel it gives more clarity to include both Asserts.

Comment: I agree with that, but what if your method does multiple things per logical run. Like sends a webservice call and persisting something in the database. Do you still assert them per logical assert? So in my case, assert the webservice call AND the saving of data all in one test?

Comment: In the case above I would mock the webservice call and the verify the call to save (when my mocked webservice call returns true), verify that there is no call to save when my mocked webservice returns false) and test for the webservice throwing an exception. You may find this article to be an interesting read. http://philcalcado.com/2010/12/14/one_mock_per_test_considered_not_awesome.html